# GLIBC_2.17 not found

Tags: linux, cpanel, glibc

I have been trying to install node js to my shared hosting server with cpanel. I have been successful to download and install node but every time try to access node via terminal it throws errors like

```
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
```

I have even downloaded glibc_2.14 via wget and also unzipped everything in the directory: `/home/glibc_2.14/configuration/`

Now I am quite confused what should i do with these files?

When i do echo `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it returns an empty string

I just want to update my glibc on my cpanel. please help... I have been trying this for so long now :(

Answer (score 2):

These errors:

```
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
```

mean that the `node` binary you are trying to install was build on a GLIBC-2.28 or later system, using GCC-5.1.0 ([ABI reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)).

You are trying to run that binary on a machine with GCC-4.4.2 and GLIBC older than 2.14. That's *not going to work*.

Trying to use GLIBC-2.14 isn't going to work either -- you need at least GLIBC-2.28.

You really shouldn't be running such an old OS -- there are many vulnerabilities that have long been fixed since then. Your best bet is to upgrade your OS to something more modern, and then install `node` compiled specifically for *that OS*.

It's *possible* to work around this by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and using `patchelf` appropriately (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) answer), but I doubt you'll succeed with that approach.

Comment: Its not like i actually want to use this OS rn but I don't have any choice. This whole thing is going on a cpanel web server. I just wanted a work around to not pay for the extra costs of the hostings which supports node js on the go. But now ig i have realised its not quite possible as the files which i am trying to install requires admin priviledges which i just cant have. Thanks for your time and answer tho. APPRICIATED.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
nvm i 16  
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
node -v
npm -v
nvm -v
```

run it several times , clean cache and relaunch the system several times